# How to add a scroll for too long data in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm a beginner and I write an App for iphone at xcode5 I have `UITextView`, it displays data which is too long and hence the last words are not displayed. Since UITextView inherits from UIScrollView I expected to see a scroll, but it is missing. How can I add a scrollbar to the UITextView?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView contains a scrollbar itself.

Comment: If the scrollbar is not displayed, how can I make it appear?

Comment: Go to storyboard, select your UITextView and select "shows Horizontal Indicator", "shows Vertical Indicator", "Scrolling Enabled". If you are creating the UITextView programmatically, you can call these corresponding functions to set them to 'YES'.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView contains a scrollbar and if you want to go down automatic on text you can use the below code:-

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1, 1);
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
```

and if it doesn’t work check whether scrollEnabled is set to YES or not in code or storyBoard.

```
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```